# Construct $A\subset\mathbb N$ with $f(A)=\sum\limits_{x\in A}\frac1x$ finite and $f(A+A)$ infinite

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, analysis

For every $U\subset\mathbb N$, define $$f(U)=\sum_{x \in U} \frac{1}{x}$$
Construct $A$ such that $f(A)$ is finite and $f(B)$ is infinite, with $B=A+A=\{x+y\mid x\in A, y\in A\}$.

Comment: What did you try? There is a simple, very tempting, case...

Comment: I can't prove the divergence of $f(B)$...

Comment: This is not my question: please explain what case(s) you tried.

Comment: $1/2^n$ or $1/n^2$

Comment: I'm not sure whether these two cases satisfy the requirement of the problem

Comment: I assume you mean (1.) $A=\{2^n\mid n\in\mathbb  N\}$ and (2.) $A=\{n^2\mid n\in\mathbb  N\}$. Obviously, $f(A)$ is finite in both cases (good). But case (1.) leads to a set $B$ which is too *thin* for $f(B)$ to diverge, so let us forget it. What did you try in case (2.)?

Comment: emm..I tried to find an inequality. let $a_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+i^2}$ ,and show that $S_n$ is divergent, which is equivalent to the divergence of $f(B)$.

Comment: Are those equivalent? You're only summing over the *distinct* values in $B$, so be careful not to count anything twice...

Comment: Golbez: Well done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A=\{n^2\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$, then $f(A)$ is obviously finite. Let us show that $f(A+A)$ is infinite. 
Note that
$f(A+A)$ is **not** in general $\sum\limits_{n\in A}\sum\limits_{k\in A}\frac1{n+k}$ since the double sum might (and often does) count several times many elements of $A+A$. Thus, we must exhibit sufficiently many elements in $A+A$ and count each of them only once. Here is a way to do this.

1. A famous theorem due to Fermat asserts that every prime $p$ such that $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$ is a sum of two squares (and that the other primes are not). Thus, $f(A+A)\geqslant\sum\limits_p\frac1p$, where the series enumerates the primes $p$ such that $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$.
2. An equally famous theorem due to Dirichlet asserts that, for every $a$ and $b$ with no common factor, $\sum\limits_p\frac1p$ diverges, where the series enumerates the primes $p$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod{b}$.
3. For $a=1$, $b=4$, this shows that $f(A+A)$ diverges.

Comment: That's nice :-)

Comment: @joriki: $\langle$ *Blushes* $\rangle$.

Comment: Good job! I found another way to do that, Let $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+i^2}$, it's easy to know that $S_n $ converges when $f(B)$ converges. When $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+i^2}>\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+i)^2}>\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{4n^2}>+\infty$ also holds

Comment: You seem to have purely and simply skipped the warning at the beginning of my post (also apparent in @Ben Millwood's comment), which, unfortunately, destroys your "argument". (Unrelated: you do not define $S_n$.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the set of positive integers whose decimal expansion is missing a certain digit, say the digit $9$. It is a [standard but interesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series) fact that the sum of the reciprocals of the elements of $A$ converges.  The proof uses little machinery.

The set $A+A$ consists of the integers $\ge 2$, so the sum  of the reciprocals of elements of $A+A$ diverges.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks for introducing Kempner series.